# Как лучше сделать чтобы не получить фильтр от Google/Yandex?

Tags: поисковые-системы

Сейчас у каждого сайта есть моб. версия. Как лучше сделать чтобы не получить фильтр от поисковой машины?

К примеру `<input type="text" class="search">`

Лучше поле с поиском скрывать c помощью `display: none;` но так получаеться на странице должно быть 2 поля с поиском, и в `css` прописывать `display: block;` для десктопной версии сайта, и `display: none;` для мобильной. И наоборот в случае с мобильной версией.

Или

Показывать нужное с помощью `php` чтобы google и yandex сообще ничего не видели.

Comment: вы боитесь получить фильтр из-за скрытого поля?

Comment: да, просто в моем случае на каждой странице будет не только 2 идентичные поля и поиском

Comment: я бы тогда парился не о поисковых системах (им плевать, сейчас у 99% процентов сайтов хренова тонна скрытых блоков есть), а о поддержке такого монстра. вам нужно посмотреть в сторону либо отдельной мобильной версии, либо освоить адаптивный дизайн (когда одни и те же элементы по разному выглядят на разных размерах монитора, без клонирования)

Comment: я использую адаптивный дизайн media queries, но, здесь просто необходимо 2 поля с поиском, так как они размещены не в одном блоке

Comment: тогда спокойно используйте их. у того же `bootstrap` есть классы типа `hidden-sm`, `visible-lg` и тд, которые и показывают блоки в зависимости от размера экрана. про поисковые системы не волнуйтесь

Comment: я думаю не стоит волноваться по этому поводу, а проверить качество мобверсии можно этими гуглоинструментами https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/mobile-friendly/ и https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=ru